# Inferred Generic Type on React Component

Tags: generics, reactjs, typescript, jsx, inferred-type

Typescript is pretty good about inferred generic types.  For example, if I write the following code:

```
class AwesomeClass<T> {
    constructor(public val: T) {
        // ...
    }

    public getVal(): T {
        return this.val;
    }
}

const inst = new AwesomeClass("Hello World");
const result = inst.getVal();
```

`result` is automatically typed to `string`.  Nifty!  I'd like to take that a step further with React.

If I make the follow component

```
interface IProps<T> {
    value: T;
    onClick: (result: T) => void;
}
interface IState { }

class AwesomeComponent<T> extends React.Component<IProps<T>, IState> {
    // ...
}
```

I'd really like it to be inferred that `value` has to have the same type as the `result` argument of `onClick`.  Instead when I initialize the component with

```
<AwesomeComponent
    value="Hello World"
    onClick={(v) => { console.log(v); }} />;
```

I get a compile error `error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'`.

**Is it possible to infer the generic type on a React element's props?**

I realize that the JSX transpiles to a call to `React.createElement` (it doesn't directly initialize the class like I do with my `AwesomeClass` example above) and that this may complicate the process - is that a deal killer?  If so, can I explicitly name a generic type using the JSX syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible yet, here's an issue about it: [Using lookahead to detect generic JSX elements?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6395).

For now what you'll need to do is:

```
interface IProps<T> {
    value: T;
    onClick: (result: T) => void;
}
interface IState { }

class AwesomeComponent<T> extends React.Component<IProps<T>, IState> {
    // ...
}

class ConcreteAwesomeComponent extends AwesomeComponent<string> {}

<ConcreteAwesomeComponent
    value="Hello World"
    onClick={(v) => { console.log(v); }} />;
```

Comment: is it possible to declare `ConcreteAwesomeComponent ` type in `JSDoc @type` comment ?

Comment: @Hassan I guess so, I've never used JSDoc so I'm not sure. But why wouldn't it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

for using functional component you can use this code

```
interface IMessagesProps<T> {
  data: T[];
  titleName: keyof T;
  type: MESSAGE_SYSTEM_TYPE;
}

const Messages = <T extends Record<keyof T, unknown>>(props: IMessagesProps<T>) => {
  const { data, type, titleName } = props;
  return (
    <>
      {data?.length ? (
        data.map((message, index) => {
           return (
            <div key={index}>
              <p >{message[titleName]}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <div>Empty</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Messages;
```

then you use Messages component like this :

```
interface IMarketNoticeResponse {
  id: string;
  message: string;
}

const messagesDisplayList : IMarketNoticeResponse[] = [
{id:"1",message:"message1"},
{id:"2",message:"message2"}]

<Messages<IMarketNoticeResponse>
      data={messagesDisplayList}
      titleName="message"
      type={messageType}
    />
```