# FlowType - Infer Generic Type on React Component

Tags: reactjs, generics, jsx, type-inference, flowtype

I have this following component

```
type PropTypes<T> = {
  items: T[],
  header: (item: T) => React.Element<*>,
  body: (item: T) => React.Element<*>,
}
type StateTypes<T> = {
  expandItem: ?T,
};

export default class Accordian<T> extends React.Component {
  props: PropTypes<T>;
  state: StateTypes<T>;
  setExpandItem: (expandItem: ?T) => void;

  constructor(props: PropTypes<T>) {
    super(props);
    ...
  }
}
```

I'd really like it to infer from `items` to know that the parameter of the `header` has the same type. Instead when I initialize the component with

```
<Accordian
    items={list}
    header={listItem => ...}
/>
```

I received:

```
-^ React element `Accordian`
20: export default class Accordian<T> extends React.Component {
                                   ^ T. This type is incompatible with. 
See: src/App/components/Accordian/index.js:20
19:   banks: GenericBank[],
             ^^^^^^^^^^^ object type
```

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895388/inferred-generic-type-on-react-component) for TypeScript, but I would like to know **is it possible to infer the generic type on a React element's props in FlowType?**

Comment: Can you provide a flow.org/try link please? I think we can help you better if we have a bit more context. 

Comment: @MichaelDeBoey [example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuYASgKYCGAxkVHnJmAOR4XWMDcqqBAntqWAAKdbABU+pAM4AeUQD4wAXjABvVGDDoCpTJIBcYUQG0AugBp1YABYUAJqTwGAFFp0HRASiUKyVAgBIAURgdUgA7AmkQOQsAX05uCTAAZQJybXF+GXklVUtSAA9scjDbAEltTHdUWK5KGHJJSTAAQUpKfFt0EtkFQu1S5t9qADoAYXpcMPDI4TgxCWyYlLSMxd6FNQBISVWBZW2NQuLSircmAEZGVC34mrq4MN3NSublI0Yrs0YAJkZvgDMjBMnA6TxoYVyTnIBl2eHQYQA5l5FAppF0AG5yFTkWLSYCYuQJaRtDp4LolMCWVy6RQqGmSWoaGzkex4OlQMJMsDAORAA)

Comment: /subscribe......

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work because in it you are initializing the accordion's state to a string.

```
class Accordian<T> extends React.Component<PropTypes<T>, StateTypes<T> {
    state = {
      expandItem: '1'
    };
}
```

A `string` is incompatible with type `T` because `T` might not always be `string`. The accordian class can't know what type T is until it is used so it needs to handle all possible types.

If you remove this state initializer the code works just fine. If you want to set the initial expanded item to be the first item in the `items` array prop you can do that too in the class constructor

```
class Accordian<T> extends React.Component<PropTypes<T>, StateTypes<T>> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.setState({
      expandItem: this.props.items[0]
    });
  }
}
```